# ProcessPoolExecuter and global variables

Tags: python, concurrent.futures

I have a question regarding global variables and using different processes.

For my main python script I have a main function which calls Initialize to initialize a global variable in Metrics.py. I've also created a getter function to retrieve this variable.

Main.py:

```
from Metrics import *
import pprint

def doMultiProcess(Files):
   result = {}

   with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
      futures = [executor.submit(ProcessFile, file) for file in Files]

   for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
      # future.result needs to be evaluated to catch any exception
      try:
         filename, distribution = f.result()

         result[filename] = {}
         result[filename] = distribution
      except Exception as e:
         pprint.pprint(e)  
   
   return result 

Files = ["A.txt", "B.txt", "C.txt"]

def main:
   Initialize()

   results = doMultiProcess(Files)
   
if __name__ == '__name__':
    main()
```

Metrics.py

```
Keywords = ['pragma', 'contract']

def Initialize():
   global Keywords
   Keywords= ['pragma', 'contract', 'function', 'is']

def GetList():
   global Keywords             # I believe this is not necessary.
   return Keywords

def ProcessFile(filename):
   # Read data and extract all the words from the file, then determine the frequency 
   # distribution of the words, using nltk.freqDist, which is stored in: freqDistTokens
   distribution = {keyword:freqDistTokens[keyword] for keyword in Keywords}

   return (filename, distribution)
```

I hope I've simplified the example enough and not left out important information. Now, what I don't understand is why the processes keep working with the initial value of Keywords which contains 'pragma' and 'contract'. I call the initialize before actually running the processes and therefore should set the global variable to something different then the initial value, right? What am I missing that is happening here.

I've worked around this by actually supplying the Keywords list to the process by using the GetList() function but I would like to understand as to why this is happening.

Comment: processes don't share variables. Every process runs `main.py` and has own `Keywords` but only main process runs `Initialize()` which changes values. You should send `Keywords` as values to processes. Or every process should run `Initialize()`

Comment: `threads` shares global variables but not `processes`. Processes would have to use module [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) to share data.